# Google Api, how to passe access_token to API call

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to use the Google analytics API. I created an account in the developer console, I use the OAuth2 to grant access to users data. So I have my refresh_token. But now, I would like to get all profilesID in GA for the account I have access to. I follow the Google's official tutorial and I get this error :

```
{
"error": {
    "errors": [{
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "message": "Login Required",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization"
    }],
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Login Required"
}
```

}

I see that i missed the credential but I dont know how to passe the access_token in this call. Here is my code :

```
$client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("APP_NAME");
    $client->setAuthConfig(GA_KEYS_JSON);

    $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
    $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

    // Get the list of accounts for the authorized user.
    $accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();
    $items = $accounts->getItems();

    var_dump($items);die();
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Look here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app#exchange-authorization-code

```
$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
$access_token = $client->getAccessToken();

$client->setAccessToken($access_token);
```

And to refresh an access token: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app#offline

Comment: thanks, but this is done at first time when you get access to the account. How to get a fresh access_token with the refresh_token ? I stored the refresh_token into my db.

Comment: See link appended in response

Comment: this is just setting a type to "offline" and I did it when i create my authURL. now I just want to get an access_token because the one I had has expired.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find a solution but may be there is another way more efficient and using the Google_Client class.

```
public function generateToken($refresh_token)
{
    $data = [
        "client_id" => "ClientID",
        "client_secret" => "SecretID",
        "refresh_token"=> "RefreshToken",
        "grant_type"=> "refresh_token"
    ];

    $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
    $res = post_request($url, $data);
    $res = json_decode($res, true); 
    return $res["access_token"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());

can be used to get a new access token when you can supply the refresh token.

The following is some code ripped from my sample project.  [Google analytics v3](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Google%20Analytics%20API/v3)

[oauth2callback.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Google%20Analytics%20API/v3/oauth2callback.php)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/Oauth2Authentication.php';
// Start a session to persist credentials.
session_start();
// Handle authorization flow from the server.
if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client = buildClient();
    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
    $client = buildClient();
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']); // Exchange the authencation code for a refresh token and access token.
    // Add access token and refresh token to seession.
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $_SESSION['refresh_token'] = $client->getRefreshToken();    
    //Redirect back to main script
    $redirect_uri = str_replace("oauth2callback.php",$_SESSION['mainScript'],$client->getRedirectUri());    
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

[oauth2authncation.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Google%20Analytics%20API/v3/Oauth2Authentication.php)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
/**
 * Gets the Google client refreshing auth if needed.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Initializes a client object.
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getGoogleClient() {
    $client = getOauth2Client();
    // Refresh the token if it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
return $client;
}
/**
 * Builds the Google client object.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Scopes will need to be changed depending upon the API's being accessed.
 * Example:  array(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY, Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS)
 * List of Google Scopes: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function buildClient(){

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAccessType("offline");        // offline access.  Will result in a refresh token
    $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
    $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
    $client->addScope([YOUR SCOPES HERE]);
    $client->setRedirectUri(getRedirectUri());  
    return $client;
}
/**
 * Builds the redirect uri.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/installed-app#choosingredirecturi
 * Hostname and current server path are needed to redirect to oauth2callback.php
 * @return A redirect uri.
 */
function getRedirectUri(){
    //Building Redirect URI
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];                    //returns the current URL
    if(strrpos($url, '?') > 0)
        $url = substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '?') );  // Removing any parameters.
    $folder = substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '/') );   // Removeing current file.
    return (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $folder. '/oauth2callback.php';
}
/**
 * Authenticating to Google using Oauth2
 * Documentation:  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Returns a Google client with refresh token and access tokens set. 
 *  If not authencated then we will redirect to request authencation.
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getOauth2Client() {
    try {

        $client = buildClient();

        // Set the refresh token on the client. 
        if (isset($_SESSION['refresh_token']) && $_SESSION['refresh_token']) {
            $client->refreshToken($_SESSION['refresh_token']);
        }

        // If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
        // else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {

            // Set the access token on the client.
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);                 

            // Refresh the access token if it's expired.
            if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {              
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken()); 
                $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();              
            }           
            return $client; 
        } else {
            // We do not have access request access.
            header('Location: ' . filter_var( $client->getRedirectUri(), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a better solution using Google_Client() class :

```
$client->refreshToken($theRefreshTokenYouHadStored);
```

So no need to do a POST request to get the fresh token, all of this is done implicitly bu refreshToken() method.

Thanks a lot for all your contributions!